# Serve different cache versions using the same URL through cloudflare worker

Tags: javascript, caching, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

There's a very common problem I have seen from many people who use different versions of their site for mobile and desktop, many themes have this feature. The issue is Cloudflare caches the same page regardless of the user device causing mixes and inconsistencies between desktop and mobile versions.

The most common solution is to separate the mobile version into another URL, but in my case, I want to use the same URL and make Cloudflare cache work for both desktop and mobile properly.

I found [this](https://findwork.dev/blog/caching-tricks-with-cloudflare-workers/) very nice guide showing how to fix this issue, however, the worker code seems to be outdated, I had to modify some parts to make it work.

I created a new subdomain for my workers and then assigned the route to my site so it starts running.

The worker is caching everything, however, it does not have the desired feature of having different cached versions according to the device.

```
async function run(event) {
  const { request } = event;

  const cache = caches.default;

  // Read the user agent of the request
  const ua = request.headers.get('user-agent');
  let uaValue;


  if (ua.match(/mobile/i)) {
    uaValue = 'mobile';
  } else {
    uaValue = 'desktop';
  }

  console.log(uaValue);

  // Construct a new response object which distinguishes the cache key by device
  // type.
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  url.searchParams.set('ua', uaValue);
  const newRequest = new Request(url, request);

  let response = await cache.match(newRequest);
  if (!response) {
    // Use the original request object when fetching the response from the
    // server to avoid passing on the query parameters to our backend.
    response = await fetch(request, { cf: { cacheTtl: 14400 } });

    // Store the cached response with our extended query parameters.
    event.waitUntil(cache.put(newRequest, response.clone()));
  }

  return response;
}

addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(run(event));
});
```

it is indeed detecting the right user agent, but it should be having two separate cache versions according to the assigned query string...

I think maybe I'm missing some configuration, I don't know why it's not working as expected. As it is right now I still get mixed my mobile and desktop cache versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `fetch()` itself already does normal caching, independent of your use of the Cache API around it. So `fetch()` might still return a cached response that is for the wrong UA.

If you could make your back-end ignore the query parameter, then you could include the query in the request passed to `fetch()`, so that it correctly caches the two results differently. (Enterprise customers can use [custom cache keys](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/archive/recipes/vcl-conversion/controlling-the-cache/#custom-cache-keys) as a way to accomplish this without changing the URL.)

If you do that, then you can also remove the `cache.match()` and `cache.put()` calls since `fetch()` itself will handle caching.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to understand what you mean and implement it! infortunately my business is very very small and I cannot afford to pay for an enterprise plan, I requested the sales team if I could get only that feature of the enterprice plan and get custom pricing that could match my budget but they told me that's not possible.

Comment: Hooray!! it worked!!! omg thank you so much!! You can't imagine for how long I have been trying to achieve this! I removed what you told me and used `newRequeset` in the fetch call instead of the original request, then created a page rule with `Cache Level: Ignore Query String` and now it is working as expected. OMG this is nice. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hmm, I would think that setting the cache level to `Ignore Query String` would be the opposite of what you want. The whole point of the query string was to cache the resources separately...

Comment: I think you're right, well, I think that the page rule is being ignored, indeed all my page rules are ignored, I had to code myself the URLs where I need to bypass cache. For some reason if I enamble my worker then cloudflare ignores my page rules.